Why is the oil drop in Milikan's oil drop experiment negative?
I read that the oil drop gains excess electrons while it is between the 2 charged plates, and I found a question which asked this but it has no answer, could someone help me understand why? Thank you

In Millikan's experiment X-rays were used to ionise the air around the oil drops. Ionisation produced positively charged air molecules and free electrons, but air molecules, ionised or otherwise, have a mean free path of less that $0.1\,\mu m$ at STP while the free electrons can travel several millimeters. That means the charge picked up by the oil drops was overwhelmingly negative.
That is, the X-rays produced free electrons, then those electrons collided with oil drops and that gave the oil drops their negative charge.

Plus any oil drop that ended up with a positive charge would not be levitated by the applied field, but accelerated downward, exiting the experiment faster than an uncharged drop.

@JonCuster Indeed, when I did the experiment (without an external source of ionization), we could see lots of neutral drops, a few levitating negative drops, and an even smaller number of careening positive drops.  Only the negative drops had something we could measure though.
